# Some questions about the description about memtest86 CD/DVD ISO

Tags: memtest86+

I have some questions about the memtest86 CD/DVD ISO

https://www.memtest86.com/tech_booting-cd-dvd.html

It says

"CD/DVD ISO images are no longer supported....we provide an (unsupported) CD/DVD ISO image of MemTest86 Free Edition for download."

OK

Then it says these things i've labelled as "A" and "B"

A) "CD/DVD boot support is inconsistent on UEFI systems,.."

B) "CD/DVD boot may not work out-of-the box; The BIOS must configured with the correct boot options (eg. boot order, **disable CSM**)"

Looking at "A" and "B". If "A" is true, isn't there an error in "B".

i.e. If they don't support UEFI then wouldn't they want CSM to be **enabled**?

By the way, this is the contents of the CD/DVD ISO

```
F:\>dir /a
 Volume in drive F is CDROM
 Volume Serial Number is 4FCB-1985

 Directory of F:\

08/05/2020  07:38             2,048 BOOT.CAT
08/05/2020  07:38       524,288,000 MEMTEST.IMG
               2 File(s)    524,290,048 bytes
               0 Dir(s)               0 bytes free

F:\>
```

This suggests to me that it's not EFI, since I understand that EFI would have an .efi file within a directory, and there's no EFI file there only two files.

So it looks to me that their claim  "A" is true.

So is their claim "B" incorrect?

Comment: The ISO is bootable as UEFI boot on a vmware virtual machine with UEFI firmware. Open the ISO using PowerISO and extract boot image. It extracts to memtest86-iso.bif. Now using 7zip open the .bif. There's memtest 86.img file which again can be mounted in 7zip. It looks like the boot image which has typical UEFI boot structure. /EFI/BOOT/  (32 bit and 64 bit .EFI files therein)

Comment: @patkim thanks, I think I found in in 7zip, it's madness https://i.imgur.com/7b89ZaC.png   `C:\Users\User\Downloads\memtest86-iso.zip\memtest86-iso.iso\MEMTEST.IMG\MemTest86.img\`

Comment: @patkim how would you explain the "A" then? Also, maybe you can answer https://superuser.com/questions/1588203/unable-to-burn-memtest86-img-efi-image-to-dvd