# unable to burn memtest86.img EFI image to DVD

Tags: windows, iso-image, dvd-burning, memtest86+, memtest

I looked https://www.memtest86.com/tech_booting-cd-dvd.html

and I downloaded the file they link to there https://www.memtest86.com/downloads/memtest86-iso.zip

And within it i'm not entirely sure what file is the image file i'm meant to burn, but I found the memtest86 ISO deeply nested within the directory structure of it, having opened it in 7zip to browse it to find that.

[image]

So having downloaded memtest86-iso.zip then opening it in 7-zip,  I found

`C:\Users\User\Downloads\memtest86-iso.zip\memtest86-iso.iso\MEMTEST.IMG\MemTest86.img\`

Within this zip file memtest86-iso.zip, there's this iso file `memtest86-iso.iso` and i'm not sure if that is meant to be burnt, but within that, there's a "[boot]" directory, a boot.cat file, and a MEMTEST.img file.   The memtest.img file is not meant to be burnt, because within that, are simply two img files. One called "EFI System Partition.img" and one called MemTest86.img   And that looks like a file to burn.

I copied MemTest86.img to my Downloads folder  so got `C:\Users\User\Downloads\Memtest86.img`

Then I tried to burn it with PowerISO.

When I open PowerISO it says that the unregistered PowerISO can't create or edit images over 300M. Well that's fine 'cos the image is 261MB and i'm not trying to edit it just burn it.

But PowerISO gives an error here

[image]

And Windows also. If I right click the img file and do "open with" and "windows disc image burner" it says "the selected disc image file isn't valid"

[image]

**Added**

Since within the Zip is a file `memtest86-iso.iso`  it has been suggested that I try burning that.  I did try burning that and a computer I tried the DVD in didn't boot with it.   Looking at the files within the ISO, (as sometimes they can indicate e.g. if the ISO requires UEFI or requires legacy), I don't see anything I recognise as bootable. It doesn't look like legacy DOS OS, or legacy linux OS.. and no dot EFI file. So that makes me wonder if it is bootable. See the contents of it below

[image]

And I tried it in virtualbox but didn't manage to boot off it. See virtualbox didn't recognise it as bootable media. (Note that I can't see an option in virtualbox to switch between UEFI or not, but I think it's legacy judging by the lack of an .efi file and efi folder, and virtualbox should be fine with legacy/BIOS)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to burn the ISO file in question to a disk?

Comment: @Ramhound: "The author wants to use a bootable optical disk not a bootable USB flash disk."

Comment: @harrymc - Yes; I know what the author is asking.  I am asking barlop if they have tried burning, the ISO in question, to an optical disk.

Comment: @Ramhound yes look at the images it's all about trying to burn to optical discs and you see the attempts and errors on attempting.

Comment: You attempted to burn the IMG file.  I asked if you attempted to burn the ISO file.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, it didn't work but i'm not sure if the ISO actually contains something bootable, maybe it's possible ti identify from the file structure? it doesn't look like efi? or a non-efi  dos, or linux..  I tried in a comp and that didn't work though not sure if the comp is the issue there, and I tried in virtualbox but it didn't work https://i.imgur.com/my99J3G.png

Comment: @barlop - Did you configure VirtualBox to use UEFI mode?

Comment: AT Ramhound maybe virtualbox doesn't support UEFI https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7702  note, that link only mentions UEFI in the context of windows. I chose "other os" when I set up the virtual machine, I doubt it makes a difference what OS is picked, I think maybe it might just do some virtual hardware optimizations if a particular OS is chosen.  I see no UEFI option in virtualbox

Comment: I think I might have better luck converting a USB one to DVD.. or just using a USB

Answer (score 2):

The ISO file is a CD image. You burn it as-is (not as a file, but using the image burning function of your favorite CD burning software).

7-Zip is capable of browsing various image formats (both for optical media and classic block storage), so that may be confusing.

---

The ISO image also works perfectly fine in a Hyper-V Gen2 (UEFI) VM. It is, however, *only* UEFI-bootable. So if you try it in VirtualBox, you have to switch to (U)EFI there as well; IIRC this option is only visible when certain modern operating systems are selected as the guest OS.

Comment: what do you mean "burn it as-is" what do you think I was burning it as? what's the difference between burning it as-is and burning it not as-is? what does burning it not as-is mean?

Comment: You have tried to unpack the memtest86 image **twice**, by first unpacking the zip file, then unpacking the image file inside. You should have **just unzipped it**. That's it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  it didn't work but i'm not sure if the ISO actually contains something bootable, maybe it's possible to identify from the file structure? it doesn't look like efi? or a non-efi  dos, or linux..  I tried in a comp and that didn't work though not sure if the comp is the issue there, and I tried in virtualbox but it didn't work https://i.imgur.com/my99J3G.png

Comment: Nowhere in their documentation they mention buring or using their tool to boot from a CD/DVD drive. Looks like the image is meant to be written to a USB flash drive directly.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov of course it could, it has been around for over 2 decades. It predates usb    Also, see  https://www.memtest86.com/tech_booting-cd-dvd.html   "MemTest86 v8, bootable CD/DVD ISO images are no longer supported......However, for UEFI systems that can only boot via CD/DVD media (such as systems with older UEFI implementations, or systems that only support remote boot via CD-ROM emulation through the BMC or IP KVM devices), we provide an (unsupported) CD/DVD ISO image of MemTest86 Free Edition for download."

Comment: I updated my answer. As Artem said, you unpacked too much. The ISO image is bootable, as indicated by the `[BOOT]` folder visible in 7-Zip (it does not actually exist but is a representation of the [CD boot data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard))).

Comment: So why won't virtualbox boot it then? see my question I added a screenshot.  I'm not looking for virtualbox to run it successfully but to  boot it.

Comment: Your screenshot does not tell whether you’ve set VirtualBox to EFI mode. As I state in my question, this CD image is _not_ bootable otherwise. Set the guest OS to Windows 10 x64 or something similar and you will be able to use EFI in VirtualBox.

Answer (score -2):

To create the boot USB,
download from [MemTest86 Download](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)
the free version and unpack it.

The included file `readme.txt` contains these instructions:

> - Plug in your USB drive.
> - Launch the included ImageUSB application.
> - Select your USB drive from the list (Step 1).
> - Select 'Write image to USB drive' (Step 2)
> - If it is not already selected, select the included image file (Step 3).
> - Click 'Write' (Step 4).
>
> After accepting a few more prompts this should give you a working
> bootable USB drive.

Comment: The author wants to use a bootable optical disk not a bootable USB flash disk.